# Jasmine angular 2+ testing mat dialog

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to Test does a method called when dialog was closed How can i do it?

```
  private openResendDialog(id: number) {
    const matAlertDialog = this.dialog.open(MatAlertDialogComponent, {
      disableClose: true,
      data: {
        message: this.translateService.instant('table.resend_message'),
        type: 'confirm',
      },
    });
    matAlertDialog.afterClosed()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe(result => {
        if (result) {
          this.resend(id);
        }
      });
  }
```

**SPEC.TS**

```
  it('#openResendDialog', () => {
    const openResendDialogSpy = spyOn(component.dialog,'open').and.returnValue({
      afterClosed:() => of([1]),
    } as MatDialogRef<typeof component>);
    const fakeParam = {
      disableClose: true,
      data: {
        message: translateServiceMock.instant('table.resend_message'),
        type: 'confirm',
      },
    };
    component['openResendDialog'](1);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(openResendDialogSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(MatAlertDialogComponent,fakeParam);
  })
```

how can i call resend function when dialog closed?